# Pseudo-currying in one line

Tags: functional-style

Often when I'm writing OOP code using an object-manager association I find myself doing something akin to currying the arguments to some form of delegate object or head. (Building a one-argument chained call as opposed to returning functions of one argument).

Usually I do this via a Block construct but it is the sort of simple functional programming thing that Mathematica really ought to have a built-in for.

What I mean is I have something like:

```
c[a1, a2, a3, ..., an]
```

And I would like a function PseudoCurry that upon application to the previous expression would give me:

```
c[a1][a2][a3][...][an]
```

To my deep surprise I have been unable to find such a function.

Does anyone know how I can write a one-line, functional way to do this?

I'm sure the answer is dead simple but I'm blanking on it right now.

#### Update

Thanks to both Bob Hanlon and Mr. Wizard for the answers.

I think this from Bob:

```
Pseudocurry[h_[a__]] := Fold[#1[#2] &, {h, a}];
Pseudocurry~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
```

is the cleanest way to do this without using deprecated functions but Mr. Wizard's

```
Pseudocurry[h_[a__]] := HeadCompose[h, a];
Pseudocurry~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
```

is the clear winner for simplicity, although `HeadCompose` is deprecated.

Comment: To clarify you don't need help getting the expression `c[a1][a2][a3][...][an]` to evaluate as you want but instead you wish to generate that expression from `c[a1, a2, a3, ..., an]`?

Comment: Just use a conditional downvalue with recursion or Nest

Comment: @Mr.Wizard exactly. For simplicity assume it's inert.

Comment: Curious side note, try: `expr = c[Apply[Sequence]@Range@1000]; Pseudocurry[Evaluate@expr]` (yields red `MaxFormatDepthExceeded` in output string )

Comment: Do you mean the `MaxFormatDepthExceeded` issue in viewing that output? That is interesting. Certainly tells us a little bit about how the front end renders expressions.

Comment: @MB1965 yes. On my machine (Mathematica 11 on macOS) the output looks like this: `MaxFormatDepthExceeded MaxFormatDepthExceeded MaxFormatDepthExceeded[234][235]...[999][1000]`

Comment: In some cases you can also do this: `c[x__, y_] := c[x][y]`

Comment: @Algohi that's more or less what Sascha proposed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT:** Modified to cover situation when an argument is a `List`

Use [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html)

```
expr = c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5];

Fold[#1[#2] &, {c, List @@ expr} // Flatten[#, 1]&]

(*  c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]  *)

expr2 = c[a1, a2, {a31, a32, a33}, a4, a5];

Fold[#1[#2] &, {c, List @@ expr2} // Flatten[#, 1] &]

(*  c[a1][a2][{a31, a32, a33}][a4][a5]  *)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice, I thought Fold would be a good way to go. Might I suggest `Prepend[List@@expr,Head@expr]` instead, though, as the flatten would flatten any sublists in the `ai`?

Answer (score 18):

The deprecated (but valid) function `HeadCompose` basically does just that:

```
c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] /. h_[a___] :> HeadCompose[h, a]
```

> ```
> c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]
> ```

If you don't wish to use that then perhaps one of these:

```
f1 = FixedPoint[Replace[h_[x_, y__] :> h[x][y]], #] &;

f2 = # //. {x : _[_] :> x, h_[x_, y__] :> h[x][y]} &;

f3 @ h_[x___, y_] := f3[h[x]][y]
f3 @ h_[] := h
```

e.g.

```
c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] // f1
```

> ```
> c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]
> ```

Comment: `HeadCompose` is almost exactly what I wanted. Any idea why it was deprecated? Unfortunately I'm rather wary of deprecated functions.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't `c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] //. h_[x_, y__] :> h[x][y]` be simpler than having to use both `FixedPoint[]` and `Replace[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I actually wrote that and then realized that it was not general enough, e.g. `c[a1 + a2, a3 + a4, a5] //. h_[x_, y__] :> h[x][y]`

Comment: @MB1965 Wiser users than I assure me that functions like this aren't going away, so I use them. (e.g. `ToHeldExpression`; `Compose`)  I would *guess* that this function was not thought to be widely useful and was dropped from the documentation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good to know. I do know that WRI makes a big deal about backwards compatibility.

Comment: `?? HeadCompose` still gives the basic usage.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, any chance you could look at this one? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/inline-syntax-for-curry

Answer (score 7):

Also possible (any maybe more readable) using patterns and `ReplaceRepeated`

```
c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]  //. f_[most__, last_] :> f[most][last]
```

> ```
> c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]
> ```

As indicated by @MB1965 in a comment `ReplaceRepeated` is greedily searching for any part of the expression that matches `f_[most__, last_]` so that

```
c[a1 + a2, a3 + a4, a5] //. f_[most__, last_] :> f[most][last]
```

yields

> ```
> c[a1[a2]][a3[a4]][a5]
> ```

Restricting the pattern to `c[most__, last_]` instead of `f_[most__, last_]` remedies that

```
pseudocurry[expr_] := expr //. Head[expr][most__, last_] :> Head[expr][most][last]

c[a1 + a2, a3 + a4, a5] // pseudocurry
```

> ```
> c[a1 + a2][a3 + a4][a5]
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this hits the problem @Mr.Wizard identified: `c[a1 + a2, a3 + a4, a5]` yields `c[a1[a2]][a3[a4]][a5]` under that scheme.

Comment: @MB1965 thanks for the comment, see improved answer

Answer (score 5):

Another old function `Compose` (superseeded by `Composition` but does some stuff that its supersessor doesn't):

```
pseudoCurry = Fold[Compose, #[[0]], #]&;

pseudoCurry @ c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

> `c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]`

```
pseudoCurry @ c[a1, {a2, a3}, a4 + a5]
```

> `c[a1][{a2, a3}][a4 + a5]`

Comment: ... `Fold[HeadCompose, #[[0]], #]&` gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example from the documentation of [`Construct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html) (2018):

```
Fold[Construct, Head@#, List @@ #] &@c[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

`c[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]`