# Position-based Inline syntax for Curry

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, operators

I would like to update an existing pseudo-curry function:

```
• /: h_[pre___, •, post___] := 
  Function[expr, h[pre, expr, post]];
```

that I use inline like this - the bullet (option-8 on most keyboards) can be placed in any position:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} // Map[f, •, {2}]
```

> {{f[1], f[2]}, {f[3], f[4]}}

This doesn't evaluate with `HoldAllComplete` functions like `Lookup`:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // Lookup[•, "c", 0]
```

> ..."The argument Function[expr$,expr$] is not a valid Association or a
>   \ list of rules"...

`Curry` on the other hand works, but requires a position spec:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // Curry[Lookup, {3, 1, 2}]["c", 0]
```

> 0

Is there a convenient method to convert the sequence:

```
h_[pre___, •, post___]
```

Into the position options for curry, in the example `{3,1,2}`? I tried the fragment (using `o` rather than bullet here):

```
f[o, x, z] // 
 Replace[f_[pre___, o_, post___] :> 
   Map[Position[f[pre, o, post], #] & , List[post]]]// Flatten
```

> {2,3}

Since the positions `{2,3}` correspond to just the `post` sequence and need to be shifted down to `{1,2}` and then combined with the `pre` part (here empty) this seems a long way to go.

Is there a cleaner approach?

**EDIT**

To summarize, `Curry`, unlike my pseudo-curry, works with `HoldAllComplete` functions, but requires numerical arguments to specify slots.

At least for the simple case of a single slot (as per my pseudo-curry), the inline position-based syntax is more usable.

So it's a matter of converting the `pre___` and `post___` to `Curry` numerical arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Please pardon me if I fail to grasp the actual meaning of your question, however I don't see how a more complicated syntax can be avoided (by using a position, etc.) when working with a `HoldAllComplete` function.

If the idea is to not have to manually destructure the expression the cleanest solution I can see is something like:

```
Attributes[f] = HoldFirst;
f[h_[pre___, •, post___]] := Function[expr, h[pre, expr, post]]

<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // f @ Lookup[•, "c", 0]               (* output: 0 *)
```

This is no better than using `Function` directly however, i.e. `Lookup[#, "c", 0] &`, which is why I think I may be missing the point.

Attempting to answer your question directly consider [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html):

```
Attributes[ord] = HoldAllComplete;

ord[h_[arg___]] :=
 Block[{•}, Replace[Hold[arg], {• -> 1, _ -> 0}, {1}]] // Ordering // Ordering

ord @ Lookup[•, "c", 0]
```

> ```
> {3, 1, 2}
> ```

Comment: `Curry` is new in 11.3: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html

Comment: @Kuba Thanks; I wondered about that.  Since I'm not yet familiar with it do you think it has a place here?  I mean is there a point to generating a position specification rather than the more direct approach?

Comment: Sorry, can't focus on this topic right now. Originally I was confused too that is why I didn't say anything about the case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `Curry` definitely has a place here, precisely because it can curry `HoldAllComplete` functions. But it requires numerical arguments to specify slots, whereas at least for the simple case of a single slot (as per my pseudo-curry), the inline position-based syntax is more usable. So it's a matter of converting the `pre___` and `post___` to `Curry` numerical arguments.  Will update my Q with this comment.

Comment: @alancalvitti Alright.  I'll have to read about `Curry` at some point.  For now does my answer solve your problem?  Also do you find use in my `f` construct which also works with `HoldAllComplete` functions, at least in the manner shown?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I should have stated the objective in using the bullet is to streamline query compositions eg  `g /* h[x,o,y] /* k` - where 'o' = bullet, this often saves a set of parentheses too `(h[x,#,y]&)`. I think your method for `f` would hinder this aim in this context.