# Cleanest way to take a[b[c]] to a[b][c]

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, functional-style

As indicated in the title I'm looking for the fastest way to transform `a[b[c]]` into `a[b][c]`, and the natural generalization to an arbitrary chaining of arguments.  I'm sure there's got to be a convenient way that I've overlooked.

In my cases `a`, `b`, and `c` can be any expression with any complicated internal structure they like.

As an example, we could have some terrible deeply nested thing like:

```
bleh =
  Nest[f, 10, 10]@
   Nest[b, 100, 100]@Nest[c, RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}], 1000];
```

And then we can to convert this into:

```
blehm =
  Nest[f, 10, 10][
   Nest[b, 100, 100]][Nest[c, RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}], 1000]]
```

Comment: The solution likely would use `Operate`.

Comment: `f = Curry[Replace][a_[b_[c_]] :> a[b][c]]` also works, so that `a[b[c]] // f` gives the desired result.

Comment: How about generalizing the question to taking `a[b[c[d[...]]]]` to `a[b][c][d]...`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  sorry I thought that was implicit

Comment: @b3m2a1:  Oh.... well I recommend you alter the question... and seem my new solution.

Comment: I'm just curious: is the reason behind the question being able to rewrite terms like `a@b[c]@d` as `a[b[c]][d]`? It's just that I have been looking for a left-associative counterpart of `@` for some time and this question is just what I need!

Comment: If you want `a b c` to be any expression you better show some examples, what is `a[b[c], d[e, f]]` supposed to be converted to?

Comment: @Kuba that's exactly what I wrangled with in the way I implemented this. I don't really know what to do with multi argument functions. So I assumed a chain of one-argument functions. At this point I'm not sure my question is well-defined though so I'm just enjoying people's creativity and up-voting everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Operate[#[[0]], First@#] &[a[b[c]]]
```

> a[b][c]

```
ClearAll[deCompose]
deCompose = Nest[Operate[#[[0]], First@#] &, #, Depth[#] - 2] &;

deCompose@a[b[c]]
```

> a[b][c]

```
exp = Compose[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

> a[b[c[d[e[f[g]]]]]]

```
deCompose @ exp
```

> a[b][c][d][e][f][g]

Answer (score 24):

```
test = a[b[c[d]]];

Fold[
  Construct,   (* or Compose, see [1] *)
  Level[test, {-1}, Heads -> True]
]
```

> ```
> a[b][c][d]
> ```

[1] - [Is there a name for #1@#2&?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28778/5478)

Alternatively, thanks to OP and Mr.Wizard:

```
HeadCompose @@ Level[test, {-1}, Heads -> True]
```

Comment: No `Operate`, No `#` and no `_`, a clear winner here :P

Comment: Oh A+ that's slick

Comment: One issue is that this will die on nested stuff like my example case, but I still like how clean this is. You could even get away with ``HeadCompose @@ Level[test, {-1}, Heads -> True]``

Comment: @b3m2a1 If I only knew about `HeadCompose` :) I am not sure about general problem so I will leave the solution for the initial one now.

Comment: I learned about it from the Wiz back [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134316/38205)

Comment: I didn't know about `Construct` but I can immediately see places to use it.  +1!

Comment: @evanb `Compose` will do as well.

Comment: +1, ++clever.  yet another variant: `Level[test, {-1}, HeadCompose, Heads -> True]`

Answer (score 10):

This works on any level:

```
a[b[c]] //. x_[s : _[_]] :> Operate[x, s]
(* a[b][c] *)

a[b[c[d[e[f[g[h]]]]]]] //. x_[s : _[_]] :> Operate[x, s]
(* a[b][c][d][e][f][g][h] *)
```

simpler syntax but same thing:

```
a[b[c[d[e[f[g[h]]]]]]] //. x_[y_[z_]] -> x[y][z]
(* a[b][c][d][e][f][g][h] *)
```

Of course, if the components `a`, `b`, `c` etc. have such complicated internal structure that they match the pattern `x_[s:_[_]]` (equivalent to `x_[y_[z_]]`), then this proposed solution will fail by over-matching. This could be remedied by constraining the pattern and fixing which elements must be atomic with `_?AtomQ`. It all depends on the use case.

This way of pattern matching can also be expanded to specific other situations like `a[b[c],d[e]]` etc., depending on what result is desired.

Comment: For your terribly nested example, what characterizes the composition is that none of the components are atomic. With `NotAtomQ[x_] := !AtomQ[x]` we have `blehm == bleh //. x_?NotAtomQ[s : _?NotAtomQ[_?NotAtomQ]] :> Operate[x, s]`. This breaks the `a[b[c]]` example though. I find that pattern matching gives more fine-grained control than `Level` in this situation.

Comment: Or perhaps `a[b[c[d[e[f]]]]] //. a_[b_[c_]] :> a[b][c]`.

Comment: @march that's exactly the same as I wrote, just using a slightly different syntax. Yes maybe your version is clearer, sorry for being so cryptic.

Answer (score 5):

Not particularly "clean," but it works:

```
Operate[Head[#], Level[#, 2][[2]]] & @ a[b[c]]
```

For the full generalization:

```
Nest[Operate[Head[#], Level[#, 2][[2]]] & , #, Depth[#] -2] & @
 a[b[c[d[e]]]]
```